# Matching string with spaces in random places?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have some string as input, for example: `sometext`
What pattern do I have to use to match it in strings with spaces and dots in any place:

1. `sometext`
2. `some text`
3. `so metex.t`
4. `111 s.o.m.e t e x t 222`

Replacing spaces and dots is not a solution because I need the original matched piece to highlight.

Comment: Are you after a regex that matches the letters s,o,m,e,t,e,x,t in order, where sometext could be any randow string? or are you specifically after a regex that ignores spaces and fullstops? your question is wide open to interpretation and is getting voted down for good reason. Try to be a bit more specific in what you want and give examples of what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: I'm after a regex that ignores spaces and fullstops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/s\W*o\W*m\W*e\W*t\W*e\W*x\W*t/
```

```
>>> foo = "sometext"
    bar = "sometext|some text|so metex.t|111 s.o.m.e t e x t 222".split(/\|/g)

    regex = new RegExp(foo.split(/|/g).join('\\W*'))
    console.log(regex)

    arr = []
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      arr.push(regex.exec(bar[i])[0])

    arr

<<< /s\W*o\W*m\W*e\W*t\W*e\W*x\W*t/
... ["sometext", "some text", "so metex.t", "s.o.m.e t e x t"]
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Correct way to anchor! Depends on what OP means by "match", the anchors will not be needed for matching the words from existing strings, while they will be needed if used to validate sequences.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, just thought there's some flag that can do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can strip off spaces/other characters first and check the remaining for a match like:

```
yourString.replace(/[ .]+/g, '').match(/sometext/)
```

Comment: I have to use the original matched piece (with spaces)

Comment: Your original isn't modified above. Btw, you can always use a more elaborate regular expression to match it with/without spaces/dots. Just thought I'll suggest a cleaner/shorter option. :-)

Comment: i.e. Something like `'some.te x.t'.match(/[ .]*s[ .]*o[ .]*m[ .]*e[ .]*t[ .]*e[ .]*x[ .]*t[ .]*/)`